# Python using melt how to frame this data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

Having data like as follows - I need to group with respect address and Trans into 2 columns - can help using melt or any other function in python?

> ```
> Id    name    address1   tran1    address2    tran2     address32     tran3
> 1     Vasu    chennai    3432     tamb        4432      cam           0121
> 2     het     tamil      32432    cheai       43543     vsda          3432
> 3     sfds    andh       12321    hyd         6754      nizh          7657
> ```

---

> Need this data as
>
> ```
> **************************
> Id******name*****address*****Tran
> 1*****Vasu******chennai*****3432
> 2****het********tamil*******32432    
> 3***sfds******* andh*******12321    
> 1***Vasu*******tamb********4432      
> 2*****het******cheai*******43543     
> 3*****sfds****hyd**********6754      
> 1****Vasu*****cam*********0121
> 2****het*****vsda********3432    
> 3****sfds****nizh*******7657
> ```

thanks

> Tried in this way getting the result in different manner
>
> ```
> data = pd.read_csv('C:DOCUMENTS/SAMP.csv') 
> melt_data1 = pd.melt(data, 
>                      id_vars=['id', 'name'], 
>                      value_vars=['address1','tran1','address2','tran2','address32','tran3'],
>                      var_name='Address', 'tRAN', 
>                      value_name='Values') 
> melt_data1.to_csv('c:/DOCUMENTS/SAM.CSV)
> ```

Comment: make an attempt yourself and then if you run into trouble provide a [mcve] of your code

Comment: Tried in this way getting the result in different manner data = pd.read_csv('C:DOCUMENTS/SAMP.csv')
melt_data1 = pd.melt(data,
id_vars=['id', 'name'
value_vars=['address1','tran1','address2','tran2','address32','tran3'],
 var_name='Address''tRAN',
  value_name='Values')
 melt_data1.to_csv('c:/DOCUMENTS/SAM.CSV)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use pd.concat for this:

```
data1 = data.loc[:,['name','address1','tran1']].rename(columns={"address1": 
"address", "tran1": "tran"})
data2 = data.loc[:,['name','address2','tran2']].rename(columns={"address2": 
"address", "tran2": "tran"})
data3 = data.loc[:,['name','address3','tran3']].rename(columns={"address3": 
"address", "tran3": "tran"})

pd.concat([ data1 , data2 , data3])
```